# Working with cells

Tags: excel, vba, cells

I got the following simple functions:

```
Public Function AddFields(field1 As Range, field2 As Range) As String
    AddFields = "=" + field1.Address + "+" + field2.Address
End Function


Private Function GetCustomerCount(monthNumber As Integer) As Range
    If monthNumber < 6 Then
        GetCustomerCount = Range("D13")
    ElseIf monthNumber < 12 Then
        GetCustomerCount = Range("D14")
    Else
        GetCustomerCount = Range("D15")
    End If
End Function
```

Which I call from the following sub:

```
Private Sub mDateLooper_OnMonth(looper As DateLooper)
    Cells(looper.Row, looper.Column).Value = "Månad " & CStr(looper.MonthIndex + 1)
    Cells(looper.Row + 1, looper.Column).Value = AddFields(GetCustomerCount(looper.MonthIndex + 1), Range("m21"))
    Cells(looper.Row + 2, looper.Column).Value = AddFields(Cells(looper.Row + 1, looper.Column - 1), Cells(looper.Row, looper.Column))
End Sub
```

It doesn't work. I get the following error: **Object variable or with block not set.**

on *GetCustomerCount = Range("D13")*.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetCustomerCount is a `Range`

If you want to assign it a new Value / Range you need to do this with set.

```
    Set GetCustomerCount = Range("D13")
```

Comment: In Tools->Options you might want to enable "Require Variable Declaration" - it's a little inconvenient at first but makes sure you have all your ducks in a row before you start getting weird errors.

What Marg mentioned is an easily-forgettable convention of VBA: "normal variables" such as integers, longs, and strings are normally assigned with i = 4 or userName = "John Smith".  Anything else, ranges, worksheets, etc., are objects and need to use they keyword "Set" as in Marg's example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to identify which sheet the Range applies to, i.e. ActiveSheet.Range("D13")